# Find the point on OY

Tags: analytic-geometry

The task is:

Given points $M(-3,2)$ and $N(2,5)$. Find a point $P$ on $OY$ that $|MP-NP|$* is maximum.(You are not allowed to use anything(vectors) except the general equation of straight line and the definition of the distance between two points)

I found a symmetric point to $N$ : $N'(-2,5)$. And as I understood the next step is to find the line $l$ between $N'$ and $M$ : $3x-y+11=0$ and than intersection $l \cap OY=P(0,11)$.But why $|MP-NP|$ is maximum I still can't understand.

(*MP-the distance between M and P)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks straight forward, if tedious, to me.  The equation of line MN is y= (3/5)x+ 19/5.  Writing P as (a, b), distance MP is $\sqrt{a+ 3)^2+ (b- 2)^2}$ and PN is $\sqrt{(a- 2)^2+ (b- 5)^2}$.  So the problem is to maximize $\left|\sqrt{(a+ 3)^2+ (b- 2)^2}- \sqrt{(a- 2)^2+ (b- 5)^2}\right|$ with the condition that $b= (3/5)a+ 19/5$.  You could either replace b by that in the quantity to be maximized or use "Lagrange multipliers".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that the distances $NP$ and $N'P$ are equal (check why).

Now, you can draw a triangle with sides $N'P$, $MP$ and $MN'$. You always have
$$MN' + N'P \ge MP,$$
where the equality is true only when the three sides lie on the same line (see [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality)). That's only possible in the case you have described. And, thus,
$$MN' \ge MP - N'P.$$